# Suppress QLineEdit editingFinished signal when certain button is clicked

Tags: qt, pyqt, focus, qt-signals

I have an (existing) Widget that is composed of a QLineEdit and a QToolButton. The code I'm building upon can be found here: https://github.com/wbsoft/frescobaldi/blob/master/frescobaldi_app/widgets/urlrequester.py

I'm trying to add the `editingFinished` signal to that composed widget, which works reasonably well by creating a new signal with `editingFinished = pyqtSignal()`, connecting the line edit's signal to a local method and emit the custom signal from that.

However, I want to suppress that signal when the tool button is pressed. But obviously when pressing the tool button *first* the `editingFinished` signal of the line edit is emitted and *then* the `clicked` signal of the button.

**Question:** Is there any way to suppress the signal when it has been triggered by a specific cause (the button click). Or is there an information that tells me what the next element is that is going to get the focus? I'm thinking of checking which widget is about to get the focus, and if it's the tool button suppress the emission of the signal.

Comment: First: you can connect a signal to another signal, so you don't need the local method to emit it explicitly. About your problem, it looks counter-intuitive to me that the signal is not emitted when you click on the button, you would expect to get it every-time the editing is actually finished (no matter who gets the focus).

Comment: The problem is: If I edit the lineedit manually and then click on the button the content in the lineedit may be invalid. I want the consumer of that widget to be able to validate the linedit a) when I move somewhere else, b) when the dialog (through the tool button) has been completed but not c) when I edited the lineedit and click on the tool button.

Comment: Or put the other way: I would like to see the lineedit and the toolbutton/dialog as *one* atomic edit process (as it is one combined widget)